# JSON to AVRO Conversion (NiFi) - some fields as value, some containing multiple JSON entries

Tags: json, xml, avro, apache-nifi

I am trying to convert JSON to AVRO - after having converted XML to JSON.
The XML/JSON contains some areas ("ID") that are fix and others ("FIELD") that are dynamic (i.e. 0-n seperate values).

```
`   <xml>
     <ID>1234567890ABC</ID>
     <FIELD>
      <A>ABC</A>
      <B>XYZ</B>
     </FIELD>
    </xml>
  <xml>
   <ID>0987654321XYZ</ID>
   <FIELD>
      <A>ABC</A>
      <C>XYZ</C>
      <F>123</F>
   </FIELD>
  </xml>`
```

Can I define an **avro schema** for NiFi's ConvertJSONtoAVRO processor (for later storing that Avro data in a hive table) that puts the **"ID" in one column** and **everything inside "FIELD" into a second column**?

Thank you sincerely!
Daniel